# Recalc Parent Form Without Losing Focus From The Current Record Of The SubForm

Tags: vba, ms-access

In access database I have a Main Form with a Tabular SubForm. I want each of the Main Form's control being recalculated upon changing any value of any record of the Sub Form.
I tried applying something like (me.parent.recalc) to each of the subform's control but found that now when I change "any" of the subform's record the focus would offset to the same field of subform's first record.
Any solution?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sub form control on the main form is named `ctlSubForm`, this would be a code sample you call in the subform, for example in an `AfterUpdate` event procedure:

```vb
'Store the current sub forms record/bookmark
Dim currentRecord As Variant
currentRecord = Me.Bookmark

'Requery the main form, causing the first record of subform will be selected
'(instead place your existing code here)
Me.Parent.Requery

'Set the sub forms record/bookmark to the stored record/bookmark
Me.Bookmark = currentRecord

'Set the focus to the main forms sub form control
'(this is necessary to really get the focus back to the subform)
Me.Parent.ctlSubForm.SetFocus
```

Answer (score 0):

Try me.parent.recordset.requery
That should refresh only underlying recordset, not the form itself. I am not shure 100% about syntax but I use that approach in my Access projects.