# How to retain focus on selected record on a subform?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a `subForm` which is not linked with the `parentForm`. I select a record from `subForm` by clicking and then run a code via `On_Click()` event of `subForm`:

```
 DoCmd.GoToRecord, acDataForm, "parentForm", acGoTo, me.Form.CurrentRecord
```

It updates the `parentForm` to desired record, however also refreshes the `subForm` due to which focus moves away from the record I clicked on initially.

How can I retain the focus on selected record on that `subForm`?

Answer (score 1):

So finally, I found an answer to my problem.

Run the code below to move to certain record on `parentForm` by clicking a certain record on `continuous subForm` that is not linked with `parentForm`. `Me.CurrentRecord` is not a reliable way to move `parentForm` record in cases where `subForm` is being filtered on some other parameters other than the `ID` and is also not `linked` to the `parentForm`. Therefore, I revised my code where I setup an SQL query and then made that as `RecordSource` of `parentForm`. I put this new code in `On_Click()` event of subForm.

```
Dim lngPosition as Long
Dim SQL1 as String
Dim a as Long

a = Me.txt_ID     'It is shared unique ID between mainForm and subForm

lngPosition = Me.CurrentRecord

SQL1 = "SELECT myTbl.a, myTbl.b, mTbl.c FROM myTbl " _
        & "WHERE ((myTbl.a) = " & a & ");"

Me.Parent.RecordSource = SQL1
Me.Parent.Requery

Me.Form.Recordset.Move lngPosition - 1
```

Upon running this, the focus remains on the active record of the `subForm` that I had initially clicked while `mainForm` is moved to the desired record.

Comment: Please click the green checkmark to close this question as answered. This will give you points and keep others from thinking that you still need help.

Answer (score 0):

I already wrote an answer here ([Recalc Parent Form Without Losing Focus From The Current Record Of The SubForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55194505/recalc-parent-form-without-losing-focus-from-the-current-record-of-the-subform/55196525#55196525)), but I got no reply yet. That's why I don't flag your question as a duplicate.

Assuming your sub form control on the main form is named `ctlSubForm`, this would be the code you call in the sub forms `OnClick()` event::

```vb
'Store the current sub forms record/bookmark
Dim currentRecord As Variant
currentRecord = Me.Bookmark

'Your current code:
DoCmd.GoToRecord, acDataForm, "parentForm", acGoTo, me.Form.CurrentRecord

'Maybe, if it is not working, try to also use this:
'DoEvents

'Set the sub forms record/bookmark to the stored record/bookmark
Me.Bookmark = currentRecord

'Set the focus to the main forms sub form control
'(this is necessary to really get the focus back to the subform)
Me.Parent.ctlSubForm.SetFocus
```

Comment: Your code does not work to solve my problem. My subForm focus is still moving to first record rather than staying on the same one that I had selected.

Comment: Hmmm, here it works, After testing now your specific constellation, I must say, that even your original code works fine for me. No need to handle that explicitely. Just saw that the `,` behind `GoToRecord` is wrong and must be removed. But I don't think that this causes the problem. Do you have more code in your `OnClick()`-event procedure?

Comment: Well, I think we have some issue with Access version here. I am on MS Access 2016. I tried removing `,` but it gave error. 
Regarding your second question, no I do not have any other code. Btw, please let me know should I put all of your code in the `On_Click()` of `subForm`? I tried running it it like this but I got error on `me.Bookmark = currentRecord` step.

Comment: In addition, my `subForm` retains the focus. However, the focus shifts to first record rather than the record I had clicked on in the `subForm`.

Comment: That's odd. The first parameter of `DoCmd.GoToRecord` is the object type, so `acDataForm`. By providing the `,` you omit this first parameter. I use Access 2013, but that shouldn't be the problem. Do you use the `OnClick` event of a button, or of which object? Whats the full name of your `OnClick` procedure?

Comment: It is `Form_OnClick()`. Because the subform I have only shows a list of numbers which are the steps of a process. The process details are being documented via main form. So, if I a select a step number by clicking the record on continuous form, the main form updates.

Comment: Now I placed your single line of code in `Form_Click()` of the sub form. Same result: All fine. I've currently just ideas for you how to solve it different: Use a ListBox instead of the sub form. Or use an unbound main form, containing to sub forms: Your current sub form and another for displaying the details.

Comment: I'm being jealous of you now :(.
I have just put all the code again as yours and got `error#3159: Not a valid Bookmark`. The issue comes on `Me.Bookmark = currentRecord`.

Comment: As I already wrote: I even don't need 'my' code at all. Your single line of code works well too. Maybe you upload a database for testing purposes for me somewhere?

Comment: I just posted an answer to my question. Finally solved it. Issue was that:
1. `subForm` was not linked with `parentForm`
2. `subForm` was being filtered so `currentRecord` of `subForm` and of `parentForm` did not match
3. `subForm` was being also `sorted` that resulted in different `currentRecord` and made it even complicated to be used for moving the `parentForm`.